# Are black holes XXXL stars?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, event-horizon, stars

Am I right to think that black holes are stars that are so dense and heavy that radiation and matter cannot leave from it's surface?

Comment: Probably not. A black hole isn't really a star, and it doesn't have a surface. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/557985/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/7913/123208

Comment: I've hidden a comment that should have been an answer, and a number of other comments discussing it. To post a brief answer, please post an answer but don't type very much in the answer box.

Answer (score 4):

> Am I right to think that blackholes are stars ...

No. A typical definition of a [star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star) is a "luminous spheroid of plasma held together by self-gravity" (note that this definition of a star not only excludes black holes but also white dwarfs and neutron "stars" too).

It is true that some (and maybe most or even all) black holes *originated* as stars before they ran out of fuel and collapsed. However, there are at least two theoretical routes to forming a black hole that do *not* involve forming a star first - they are [primordial black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primordial_black_hole) and [direct collapse black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_collapse_black_hole).

Comment: Maybe it's worth to mention that if [exotic objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_object) could be taken into consideration (such as quark "star"), then star definition exclusion list would be much longer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are envisioning a black hole as a traditional star that is simply invisible because all its light and heat emitted is pulled backwards and cannot escape.

This is not the case. A black hole is a region of spacetime where time and space behave differently. In a traditional black hole (barring some very modern papers), no extended matter can exist inside, because it will inexorably fall inward to the center.